# How to clean keyboard with a liquid with sugar spilled on it

Tags: keyboard

Well, I just spilled some sweet liquid in my aluminium wired keyboard and few keys are hard to press now. What is the best way to clean the keyboard out of the sugar? I guess I could just clean it with water and let it dry few days but I am worried about the membrane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know what’s inside an Apple Aluminium Keyboard as I don’t have one. But washing it with water and letting it dry in the **shade** for a few days should not cause a problem. If any, you should be worried about rusting any metal and not about the membrane, which is made up of rubber or plastic.

EDIT: Don’t forget to remove the batteries!!!

Comment: I'll second this. I've spilled various things on mine over the years and recently had to wash it in the sink (no soap, just lots of water!) after a bad spill. It worked just fine, but took quite a few days to dry up completely before it worked normally.

Comment: I'll third this, works for most things without displays, sensitive, or mechanical parts. In fact when I used to work for Nokia Data we used to refurb motherboards, keyboards, and mice by cleaning them under a tap and leaving them in a warm and dry room for 24 hours. Stuff that worked once more was re-used in new casings, stuff that failed went in the bin. De-ionised & filtered water is best as it leaves hardly any residue compared to tap water, but boiled and cooled water is the next best thing. Put it in an old shampoo bottle or something so that you can get some pressure from a jet on it.

Comment: Uhhhh.... Water + electronics = BAD...???

Comment: You used to refurb motherboards by running them under the tap?! Wow.

Comment: Well, keyboard just works fine :)

Comment: Glad it worked. :D

Answer (score 1):

Use isopropyl alcohol (rubbing alcohol). Remove batteries. Pour some around the keys that are hard to press, tap on them vigorously so that the alcohol reaches every spot and drain the alcohol. Leave to dry.

Comment: A sensible suggestion, rather than running it under the tap!

Comment: That will also remove the letters printed on the keys.

Comment: No, it won't. If you are unsure you can always try it first on some small fragment using cotton swab.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wikihow.com/Clean-a-Keyboard-in-a-Dishwasher

this i have heard from numerous websites, though if you have a very expensive keyboard like mine with built in macro software and other numerous features or a touch pad etc i wouldn't be to quick to slap it in the dish washer on a cool run. when my keyboard kets dirty i usually turn it upside down proceeded by lots of shaking, but that only removes dust. about once per year i just dismantle the whole thing screws on the back and all and clean the whole lot with the alcohol wipes usually you can get to the keyboard key mechanics without any problems and give them a good wipe if any have become sticky. if you keyboard does not have access to the button you can usually prize off the keys of that sort of board and clean them individually, fortunately the design of keyboard is as such that cleaning them no matter how messy can be done with little fuss and a screwdriver.

keep you screws you take out in a bowl so they don't run away, remember what order you took it to pieces (you can take photos) and then reverse the process to put it back together after cleaning. they are very hard to break. under the keys there is sometimes a white protective film on top of a rubber sleve that is always present this is on top of a white film that has the contacts that leads to a very small circuit board where you plug it into the computer.

washing electronics in water is fine. the idea behind this is that electronics only stop working when the contacts on the components break. this happens when people get electronics wet then put them someplace warm then the electronic board begins to expand under the heat, usually unevenly, this causes various components to break away from the electronic board.

so you can wet the hell out of a mother board or a phone or anything providing you do not change the temperature, no components will move, the item drys out. then you may plug it in though some electronics may take several months to dry out such a phones and you must make sure they remain at 20 degrees the whole time. if you plug it in before it drys it will short and not come on until its dry. having said all this its not great to grab a board and flush it with water unless it is your last resort because although in theory it is fine it can still warp and change things which is not so great.